# LoaderCallbacks implemented by a Standalone class that acts as datasource

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am writing a music player. I'm following `MVVM`. So the `fragmentA` needs a list of songs. This `fragment` calls a method in `ViewModelClass` that in turn uses a standalone class (implementing `LoaderCallbacks`) and returns a list of song. This `fragment` can delete a song from the list and it wants to get the new/updated list also. So I have two questions:

1) Should `activity` implement loadercallbacks itself? Would it be better? As per design considerations?

2) How should deletion be done? Should Standalone class have a method for song deletion? Or should `activity` be implementing the `LoaderCallbacks`itself and a DAO like class have method for song deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ContentOberver. This will give you callback whenever your dataset have change. [Refer this link](http://codetheory.in/asynchronous-background-execution-and-data-loading-with-loaders-framework-in-android/)